# How to customise the coupons in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, coupon

I want to apply 50% coupon to lowest product only.
If the cart has 2 products means when the customer applies the coupon "COUPON50".
**Product A = $20
Product B = $10**
then the coupons must be apply to **product B** i.e., $5 discount only.
We did googled but no clue to get going.
Am pretty new to this concepts, any help would be appreciable.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this particular condition, you have to build you own logic. I will do this by following way:

**->Get Order ID**

```
protected $_checkoutSession;


public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,

.....
) {

    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;


}

$order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
$orderId=$order->getEntityId();
$order->getIncrementId();
```

**->Get Order Items by order ID**

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
....
) {
....
$this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
....
}
```

**And for specific condition, get items price as:**

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
$itemPrice = $item->getPrice();
}
```

Now with the help from this class apply my coupon code to the particular product in custom module:

**vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost.php**

Good Luck